# fabricated models not the same as on disk

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, fabrication-gem

I'm probably misunderstanding something here.

I have a model Secondant that I create with Fabrication in my model rspec.

```
main_user = Fabricate :user, email: TESTEMAIL
sec = Fabricate :secondant, email: SECEMAIL, user_id: main_user.id
sec_user = Fabricate :user, email: SECEMAIL
ActionMailer::Base.deliveries = []
debugger
```

At this point when I look at the value of secondant_id in the sec model, the attribute is empty (it get's filled in a after_create callback). When i retrieve the model just created from the database that attribute is filled. Why are those two not in sync?

```
   27        main_user = Fabricate :user, email: TESTEMAIL
   28        sec = Fabricate :secondant, email: SECEMAIL, user_id: main_user.id
   29        sec_user = Fabricate :user, email: SECEMAIL
   30        ActionMailer::Base.deliveries = []
   31        debugger
=> 32        sec.destroy
   33      end
   34
   35      it 'should have a secondant_id assigned' do
   36        sec.secondant_id.should_not be_nil
(rdb:1) e sec
#<Secondant id: 519, user_id: 1095, email: "secondant@hotmail.com", secondant_id: nil, created_at: "2013-10-10 13:13:29", updated_at: "2013-10-10 13:13:29", reported: false>
(rdb:1) e Secondant.where(id: sec.id).first
#<Secondant id: 519, user_id: 1095, email: "secondant@hotmail.com", secondant_id: 1096, created_at: "2013-10-10 13:13:29", updated_at: "2013-10-10 13:13:29", reported: false>
```

My after_create callback:

```
  def find_user
    user = User.where(email: self.email).first

    if user
      # create the link to the user
      self.secondant_id = user.id
      self.save

      # see if this is the second one
      if Secondant.where('user_id = ? and secondant_id is not null', user_id).count == 2
        user.do_somthing
      end
    end

    return
  end
```

### EDIT

There is a similar callback in the user class, which is firing in this case (thanks Peter)

```
  def find_secondant
    Secondant.where(email: email).find_each do |sec|
      sec.secondant_id = id
      sec.save
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the time you create `sec`, the user with the identical email has not been created, so your `after_save` callback should *not* be setting `secondant_id`.

I can only assume that your `find_user` method is getting invoked as a result of the `User` creation or the `where` operation you are executing in the debugger, resulting in the `secondant_id` field being set at that time.  It won't be reflected in `sec` unless/until you do a `reload`, as the Ruby object created by `where` is distinct from the `sec` Ruby object.

Comment: My bad,there is indeed a similar one in the User class, that takes care of the secondant_id in this case. Still don't understand why the model is different than the DB.

Comment: What you're calling a "model" is just a Ruby object, existing in memory.  Its in-memory attributes/fields are only updated when you invoke a method which does that. At the time `sec` is created, `sec.secondant_id` is nil. While it's true that the `secondant_id` field of the DB record which that instance corresponds to subsequently gets updated, that won't affect `sec` until you do a `sec.reload`. Is that clear? If not, could you say more about which aspect you don't understand?

Comment: ok. And is it considered good practice to do a reload after db changes are performed so that the model and db are always in sync?

Comment: I wouldn't say so, no. I think it's entirely situational.